# Objective c: iOS 13+ programmatically setting initially root view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios13, ios14

I am trying to set an initial root view controller programmatically using SceneDelegate in iOS 14 (no storyboard at all). I have followed https://medium.com/@sapa.tech/xcode-11-3-remove-storyboard-from-project-6c48c9d11123 to remove storyboard from my app, and have seen many answers to this question in swift in [Why is manually setup root view controller showing black screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451496/why-is-manually-setup-root-view-controller-showing-black-screen), and [Set root view controller iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058914/set-root-view-controller-ios-13) and [iOS 13: Swift - 'Set application root view controller programmatically' does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084127/ios-13-swift-set-application-root-view-controller-programmatically-does-not). However, I am looking for tips on how to do it in objective C instead. So far, I have this in my scene delegate, where ViewController is the class I am trying to set as the root view controller:

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
   
    UIWindowScene * winscene = [[UIWindowScene alloc]initWithSession:session connectionOptions:connectionOptions];
    
    [self.window setWindowScene:winscene];
    ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

And in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    return YES;

}
```

I have tried to translate the Swift answers I found to objective c but I still end up with a black screen on the simulator. The app builds fine with no error, but I just cannot get the ViewController to show up instead of a black screen. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to create a UIWindowScene yourself, but to use the one given as parameter:

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithWindowScene:(UIWindowScene *)scene];
    ViewController * viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```